# use file list as menu options for theme chooser

Tags: android, menu, themes, sh

Trying to write an android/linux script to list files in specific directory as menu options then perform set of commands using that file as a variable in a script...so far I've got this:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
l_count=0
cd /sdcard/themes
ls *.zip|while read l_file
do
   l_count=`expr $l_count + 1`
   echo "${l_count}. ${l_file}"
done
echo
echo "Pick a theme:"
read $choice
```

but from there I can't figure out how to assign the number assigned from l_count to the l_file

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...answer was to have the script write out a second script while still inside the do loop. Here's the final script...

```
#!/system/bin/sh
l_count=0
cd /sdcard/themes
echo "#!/system/bin/sh" > /sdcard/themes/themer_tmp.sh
echo "echo 'Pick a theme:'" >> /sdcard/themes/themer_tmp.sh
echo "read choice" >> /sdcard/themes/themer_tmp.sh
echo case '$choice' in >> /sdcard/themes/themer_tmp.sh
ls *.zip|while read l_file
do
    l_count=`expr $l_count + 1`
    echo "${l_count}. ${l_file}"
    echo "${l_count})" >> /sdcard/themes/themer_tmp.sh
    echo echo '"boot-recovery" > /cache/recovery/command' >> /sdcard/themes/themer_tmp.sh
echo echo '"--update_package=/sdcard/themes/'${l_file}'"' '>> /cache/recovery/command' >> /sdcard/themes/themer_tmp.sh
echo echo '"--wipe_cache" >> /cache/recovery/command' >> /sdcard/themes/themer_tmp.sh
echo echo '"reboot"' '>> /cache/recovery/command' >> /sdcard/themes/themer_tmp.sh
echo "reboot recovery" >> /sdcard/themes/themer_tmp.sh
echo ";;" >> /sdcard/themes/themer_tmp.sh
done
echo "esac" >> /sdcard/themes/themer_tmp.sh
sh /sdcard/themes/themer_tmp.sh
```

Hope this helps anybody else seeking a similar solution